# Two ways of loading csv file, which one is faster when a lot of people visit the website

Tags: django, postgresql, filesystems

I am using Django with Postgresql.
Right now I am trying to load CSV file with around 2MB  and use this data to add markers on the google maps.

I have two possible solutions: One, I save CSV in the file system, every time when I load the page I will access the CSV and pass it into Django template.
[image]
Another way is to save the CSV data as columns in a table and retrieve it from the database when I load the page.

When there are lots of people visit the website, which way would be better (which way is faster)?
Thanks!

Comment: When you say save to database do you mean save the CSV data as columns in a table or save the entire file to a field? If it where me I would save to table as columns.

Comment: I just edited the question, i am planning to save CSV data as columns in a table.

Comment: I would say pulling from the database would be faster, especially if the data does not change or changes little. The only real way to verify is to test.

Comment: The only way to know which is faster in your context is to try it and see.  But faster is rarely the overriding concern. I'd usually rather have something be 2x easier to maintain, then 1% faster.  Are you already using PostgreSQL for your project, or would this be the first usage of it?  Are you already using the file system to store data (not code or config), or would this be the first usage of it?